# how to change the selected background color of table row

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have a TableLayout with three TextViews in each of its rows. Im trying to change the background color and  highlight color of selected row but its not changing.I have defined the green/red/blue color in colors.xml in values. but when I run my app and click on the row, nothing changes and the background color remain transparent. I have changed the transparent to red and the color remains red even after clicking. so I know that table row is connected to the row_selector.xml properly but it does not work properly.

This is the main xml

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context=".MainActivity"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TableLayout  


    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

   >

                 <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">



 <TableRow
     android:id="@+id/one"
      android:focusable="true"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"              

     android:background="@drawable/selector"

     android:onClick="rowClick" >

       <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="User Name"
                  android:textSize="20sp"

                  android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="" />

        </LinearLayout>

        </TableRow>



 <TableRow   
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:onClick="rowClick"
         android:focusable="true"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:background="@drawable/selector"

        >

       <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Display Name "
                 android:textSize="20sp"
                  android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"

                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="" />
        </LinearLayout>

        </TableRow>


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</TableLayout>
```

This is the selector xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item   android:state_focused="true"
            android:state_pressed="true"
            android:drawable="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"></item>
    <item   android:state_focused="true"
            android:state_pressed="false"
            android:drawable="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"></item>
    <item
            android:state_focused="false"
            android:state_pressed="true"
            android:drawable="@android:drawable/list_selector_background" />


     <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"></item>

</selector>
```

this is the list_selector_backgroung

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_selected="true" 
          android:state_pressed="false"
          android:drawable="@color/grey"></item>


    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:state_pressed="false"
          android:drawable="@color/green"></item>   


    <item android:drawable="@color/black"></item>   <!-- for other state -->        
</selector>
```

This is color xml

```
<color name="safe_mode_text">#80ffffff</color>
    <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
    <color name="green">#008000</color>
    <color name="white">#ffffffff</color>
    <color name="grey">#808080</color>
    <color name="black">#ff000000</color>
    <color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your selector.xml with like this

```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/grey" android:state_pressed="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@color/green" android:state_focused="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@color/black"/>//default

    </selector>
```

**EDIT:** Do onething, use directly with @color/...

Comment: no resource found that match the matches the given name at drawable with value  @drawable/list_selector background